# Using DbFunctions method with anonymous type New Expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda, expression-trees

I need to build an expression:

```
{
   t => new {
        field1 = t.field1,
        field2 = t.field2,
        dateTimeField = TruncateTime(t.dateTimeField)
     }
}
```

I have built expression:

```
{
     t => new {
         field1 = t.field1,
         field2 = t.field2,
         dateTimeField = t.dateTimeField
       }
 }
```

by using [LatticeUtilsAnonymousTypes](https://github.com/dotlattice/LatticeUtils/blob/master/LatticeUtils/AnonymousTypeUtils.cs), but I cannot wrap `t.dateTimeField` with a `TruncateTime` function.

Here is my code:

```
    public static Expression<Func<T, dynamic>> GroupByExpressionAnonymous(string fields,
        string groupByDateField = null)
    {

        ISet<string> propertyNames = new HashSet<string>(fields.Split(',').Select(t => t.Trim()).ToList());

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(groupByDateField))
        {
            propertyNames.Add(groupByDateField);
        }

        ParameterExpression entityParameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), @"t");

        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => propertyNames.Contains(p.Name));

        var propertyExpressions = properties.Select(p => Expression.Property(entityParameterExpression, p));

        var anonymousType = AnonymousTypeUtils.CreateType(properties.ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.PropertyType));
        var anonymousTypeConstructor = anonymousType.GetConstructors().Single();
        var anonymousTypeMembers = anonymousType.GetProperties().Cast<MemberInfo>().ToArray();

        var anonymousTypeNewExpression = Expression.New(anonymousTypeConstructor, propertyExpressions, anonymousTypeMembers);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, dynamic>>(anonymousTypeNewExpression, entityParameterExpression);
    }
```

How can I use the DbFunction Truncate to one of the expression field in such case?

Comment: You should be able to modify the second argument of `Expression.New` - it doesn't need to be property expressions, could include any type of expression. As soon as you know on which property you want to apply `TruncateTime`, it shouldn't be a problem of using some of the `Expession.Call` overloads.

Comment: Thanks! It's work!